# Mount size calculations

Tags: dnd-5e, creature-size, mount

In our latest session a party member purchased a baby triceratops. According to dnd sources baby triceratops is a medium sized being (according to TOA) and my party member is also medium size.

The player asked whether being mounted on the triceratops is considered a large creature or still medium. Are there any official rules according to the sizes of mounted beasts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all: [Triceratops](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/triceratops) is a Huge beast, not Medium (MM 80).

If it actually was Medium, then only Small and Tiny creatures could mount it. PHB 198:

> A willing creature that is **at least one size larger** than you and that has an appropriate anatomy can serve as a mount

A rider and his mount are still considered different creatures and retain their statistics, including size.

Comment: Oops, I forgot to say it was a baby. I updated the post.

Comment: @iaminsensible then your Medium-sized PC has to wait until Medium-sized baby triceratops will grow into at least Large-sized creature.